# `getimagesize` giving error `Filename cannot be empty` PHP 8

Tags: php

`getimagesize` giving error `Filename cannot be empty` PHP 8

```php
if(isset($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"])) {
    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
}
```

I do not get this error under PHP 7.3. But in PHP 8.0 the error is thrown during the file upload.

Comment: `if(!empty($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"])){`

Comment: You asked about `file_get_contents()` but I couldn't find it. There is only `getimagesize()` function called. Which function is it exactly?

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the error re-classification made for PHP8.

I advise you to check for an empty string too in your condition

```php
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]) && $_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"] !== ''){
    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
}
```

Alternatively you could `catch (ValueError $e)` but this error is pretty generic so this is not advised.

For the record you yan check the output for various PHP versions with this link: https://3v4l.org/HgXpT

The change has been made in this Pull Request https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/5902